# Outlook 2003 web links show as txt

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003

MS Outlook 2003 with all updates - suddenly incoming e-mail with URLs used to show as links - now URLs show up as txt (are not colored blue and underlined)

Comment: Does the problem only occur with incoming links, or does it also occur when you create a new message?